# React-Router, render multiple components

Tags: javascript, react.js, redux

This works but it doesn't really seem ideal. Is there a better way to write this using react-router? Initialization and pagination are just React containers holding logic. `DisplaySaves` is a component that renders some stuff to the screen.

```
<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/authorize_callback" exact component={Initialization} /> 
    <Route path="/authorize_callback" exact component={Pagination} /> 
    <Route path="/authorize_callback" exact component={DisplaySaves} /> 
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add more code, for instance .. the components?

Comment: Do they need to be rendered in all routes? If so, you can put them in a higher level outside the Router. And them you Route only what needs to change.